# Node js - mongodb not responding

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-modules

Need help, I am trying to learn nodejs from youtube. I have created below but not getting any response from browser. Can you please check below code and advise what I have missed??
if I removed the courseModel.find ... from course.js and just write resp.send("XYZ") its showing on browser otherwise nothing is showing. please help

seems something is missing in mangodb connection string

--index.js

```
const connection = require('./model/connection');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const handleBars = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const courseController = require('./controllers/course');

const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true,
}))


app.use("/course", courseController);

server.listen(3900, () => {
console.log("server is in running mode.");
});
```

--connection.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var conn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/learning", (err) => {
if (!err) {
    console.log("Mongo db connected");
} else {
    console.log(err);
}
});

const courseModels = require("./course.model");
```

--course.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
courseName: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Required'
},
courseId: {
    type: String,
},
courseDuration: {
    type: String,
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Course", CourseSchema);
```

--course.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const router = express.Router();
const courseModel = mongoose.model("Course");


router.get("/lists", (req, resp) => {

courseModel.find((err,docs)=>{
    if(!err){
        resp.send(docs)
    }
});

});

module.exports = router;
```

--logs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved after updating the connection.js as below

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/learning',
{
useNewUrlParser: true,
// useFindAndModify: false,
useUnifiedTopology: true
},  console.log("mongo db connected")

);
```

Answer (score -1):

Insted of .

```
server.listen(3900, () => {
console.log("server is in running mode.");
});
```

use :

```
app.listen(3900, () => {
console.log("server is in running mode.");
});
```

Comment: dear server is up and running but when I tried to call collections its not getting response

Comment: when i used methods to fetch data like courseModel.find((err,doc)=>{ resp.send(doc)}) its not getting repsonse

Comment: seems im missing something in connection user/password etc... can you please check if connection string is correct?

Comment: I think you are getting error from the model and you are not handeling error , please handle your erros and try again 

courseModel.find((err,docs)=>{
    if(!err){
        resp.send(docs)
    }else{
        console.log(err);
        resp.send(err.message)
    }
});